# ImportError: Spatial indexes require either `rtree` or `pygeos` in geopanda but rtree is installed

Tags: python, gis, geopandas

I am trying to clip spatial data in python but when I run my code...

```
europe = gpd.clip(worldmap, europe_bound_gdf)
```

... I get the error:

(`ImportError: Spatial indexes require either` rtree`or`pygeos`.)

When I try to install rtree using:

```
pip3 install rtree
```

I'm told:

```
Requirement already satisfied: rtree in /Users/joshuajones/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/site-packages (0.9.7`)
```

So why is my code not working?

Comment: Are you sure you install `rtree` in the same environment?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same issue and this solved it for me:

```
pip uninstall rtree
sudo apt install libspatialindex-dev
pip install rtree
```

Found the answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/379648/error-while-using-sjoin-in-geopandas).

Comment: `yay -S libspatialindex-git` If you happen to use ArchBTW

Answer (score 6):

[GStav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67673782/6045800) worked for me, but as a Mac user my steps were slightly different:

```
pip uninstall rtree
brew install spatialindex
pip install rtree
```

Comment: This worked for me when using `arch -arm64 brew install spatialindex`

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the only thing that helped:

#### install and import condalab, run twice.

```
!pip install -q condacolab -q

import condacolab

condacolab.install()
```

#### install geopandas, this could take long

```
!conda install geopandas

import geopandas as gpd
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation [here](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/getting_started/install.html), you can set geopandas to use pygeos.
**Note:** it will only work if the GeoDataFrames you use are created (e.g. reading a file with read_file) after changing this value. So do a fresh import of geopandas and run these two lines after that and next, load the geopandas dataframes again.

```
import pygeos
geopandas.options.use_pygeos = True
```