# Mapping Latitude and Longitude to shapefile containing polygon using geopandas

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I want to map Latitude and Longitude dataframe (df_raw) to a shape file (gdf_raw) that contains all the postal codes and want to save in a dataframe (df_with_pc) as shown below. Note that the latitude and longitude can also contain in the polygon i.e. inside the gdf_raw['geometry'].

**df_raw**

| id | city | country | latitude | longitude | hospital |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Alberta | CA | 51.04915 | -114.06347 | John F Kenndy |
| 1 | Alberta | CA | 51.03923 | -114.00622 | New maternity |
| 2 | Alberta | CA | 51.05330 | -113.98499 | Shine dental clinic |
| 3 | Alberta | CA | 51.06141 | -113.98238 | Heavens hospital |

Here's what I have used:

```
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df_raw['longitude'], df_raw['latitude'])]
gpd.GeoDataFrame(df_raw, crs='EPSG:4326', geometry=geometry)
```

This gives me a column in gdf_raw with geometry:

| id | city | country | latitude | longitude | hospital | geometry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Alberta | CA | 51.04915 | -114.06347 | John F Kenndy | POINT(-114.06347,51.04915) |
| 1 | Alberta | CA | 51.03923 | -114.00622 | New maternity | POINT(-114.00622 ,51.05330) |
| 2 | Alberta | CA | 51.05330 | -113.98499 | Shine dental clinic | POINT(-113.98499,51.05330) |
| 3 | Alberta | CA | 51.06141 | -113.98238 | Heavens hospital | POINT(-113.98238,51.06141) |

**gdf_raw**

| postalcode | prov | longitude | latitude | geometry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T2Z4Y6 | AB | -113.973355 | 50.927521 | POLYGON ((-113.97203 50.927157, -113.972029 50... |
| T2Z0H4 | AB | -113.973588 | 50.928317 | POLYGON ((-113.972411 50.928918, -113.972783 5... |
| T2Z4E3 | AB | 113.974361 | 50.922711 | POLYGON ((-113.973857 50.9236, -113.975285 50.... |

**df_with_pc**

| id | city | country | latitude | longitude | hospital | postalcode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Alberta | CA | 51.04915 | -114.06347 | John F Kenndy | T2P0H5 |
| 1 | Alberta | CA | 51.03923 | -114.00622 | New maternity | T2Z7X8 |
| 2 | Alberta | CA | 51.05330 | -113.98499 | Shine dental clinic | T2A4Y6 |
| 3 | Alberta | CA | 51.06141 | -113.98238 | Heavens hospital | T2A2Z5 |

I have tried geopandas.sjoin.

```
gdf_combine = gpd.sjoin(df_raw, gdf_raw)
```

And I get below error. Already tried with [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67021748/importerror-spatial-indexes-require-either-rtree-or-pygeos-in-geopanda-but)

```
ImportError: Spatial indexes require either `rtree` or `pygeos`. See installation instructions at https://geopandas.org/install.html
```

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to stack overflow. See [ask]. Before asking a question please look for other questions which answer your issue. If it truly is unique, then you need to show us what you’ve tried, where you’re stuck, and include any errors and anything necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: For this you can use geopandas.sjoin

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I used geopandas.sjoin already with error. Check my updated post.

Comment: ok. did you try to install pygeos or rtree? if you're getting an error installing one of them, that's a very different question (which has also been answered many times). If you're encountering an issue installing the dependencies, the debugging approach will depend on how you're installing them. Look for other questions related to *that* issue.